# Is there a specific word for a non-linear range of choices?

Tags: single-word-requests

I feel like there is a special word for this but I don't remember what it is.

Here is an example, a poll often has the following choices:

```
A) Strongly Disagree ... B) Disagree ... C) Agree ... D) Strongly Agree
```

And now take a look at the following set of choices:

```
What is your favorite fruit?
A) Apple ... B) Banana ... C) Orange
```

Is there a word for the above set of choices? Notice that it is not a linear set of choices like the one above it.

Someone might say that Banana is in between Apple and Orange, but I want to respond with "those choices aren't linear, they are ____". What is a word that I can use to fill the blank?

Comment: Are you thinking of [discrete](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#Terminology)?

Comment: @approxiblue That's not what I was thinking about but it is a good option. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for "multiple choice question"?

Comment: Together, the choices form an *enumeration*.

Comment: They are *independent*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're thinking of the statistics term ***nominal*** (sometimes in a compound with *scale*, *data*, *value*, etc.).

From Dictionary.com:

> [**nominal scale**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nominal-scale)
>   noun
>   1. (**statistics**) a discrete classification of data, in which data are neither measured nor ordered but subjects are merely allocated to distinct categories: for example, a record of students' course choices constitutes nominal data which could be correlated with school results
>   *Compare* ordinal scale, interval scale, ratio scale

There's a brief explanation of these various scales [here](http://www.usablestats.com/lessons/noir), from UsableStats. Your first example is *ordinal* (and specifically probably a [Likert Scale—see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale)).